# Modifying numbers in a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a variable **prix** that returns `5998 7510 8144 9458 10916 13214` and this list must be changed to `59,98 75,10 81,44 94,58 109,16 132,14` 
How can I do it. That is, add a `,` before the last 2 digits (from right) of each number ?

This is the C# code I've tried so far :

```
 XDocument docxx = XDocument.Parse(Session["xmlrs" + z + ""].ToString());
        //This now holds the set of all elements named field

        try
        {
            XNamespace foobar = "http://www.april-technologies.com";
            var prix  = docxx.Descendants(foobar + "CotisationMensuelle").Select(x => new { CotisationMensuelle =(string)x}).ToList();

            rpMyRepeater1.DataSource = prix;

            rpMyRepeater1.DataBind();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {}
```

and the C# Code is :

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rpMyRepeater1" ItemType="" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CotisationMensuelle").ToString() %>
            <br />

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: before the last 2 digits (from right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
XNamespace foobar = "http://www.april-technologies.com";
var prix  = docxx.Descendants(foobar + "CotisationMensuelle").Select(x => new { CotisationMensuelle =(string)x}).ToList();
var newPrix = new List<string>();
foreach (var s in prix)
{
    var s1 = s.CotisationMensuelle.Substring(0, s.CotisationMensuelle.Length - 2);
    var s2 = s.CotisationMensuelle.Substring(s.CotisationMensuelle.Length - 2);

    //add a comma before the last 2 digits (from right)

    var s_total = s1 +","+ s2;

    newPrix.Add(s_total);
}
rpMyRepeater1.DataSource = newPrix.Select(x => new {CotisationMensuelle = x}).ToList();
rpMyRepeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i get erreur message : `'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: i have added this   `var s_total = s1 +","+ s2;` and now i get **59,98 75,10 81,44 94,58 109,16 132,14** thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Not quite clear what you are asking as you code sample is unrelated to the list you have given as an eample. If you need to add a comma two letters from the end, try this,

```
string val = "7958";
string newVal = val.Insert(val.Length-2,",");
Console.WriteLine(newVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DataBound` event, for sample, in your page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpMyRepeater1" ItemType="" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpMyRepeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltl" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in your code behine:

```
int i = 0;
protected void rpMyRepeater1_ItemDataBound(object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // if the item on repeater is a item of data
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    {
        // get value
        string value = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "CotisationMensuelle").ToString();

        // find literal
        Literal ltl = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltl");

        // check if i < 2
        if (i < 2)
        {
            // write value
            ltl.Text = value;
            //increase i
            i++;
        }
        else 
        {
            // write value and <br/>
            ltl.Text = string.Format("{0}<br />", value);

            // zero i
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
        string data = "5998 7510 8144 9458 10916 13214";

        string newValue = string.Join(" ",
                  from s in data.Split(' ')
                  select (double.Parse(s) / 100).ToString("0.00"));
        //59,98 75,10 81,44 94,58 109,16 132,14
```